# SIGABRT Exception happens because of IBOutlets

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've got login and logout functions:

```
private func signUpAction() {
let appDelegateTemp = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegateTemp.window!.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() as! RootViewController
}

private func logOutAction() {
let appDelegateTemp = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as! LoginViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

appDelegateTemp.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

And the problem is the following: when I logout and login right after that, it causes SIGABRT exception to happen. After some research I've found out that the problem is in the IBOutlets, which appear to no longer  have owners. 
Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you show the login function as well?

Comment: @ZacKwan `signUpAction()` does login functionality, sorry for bad naming

Comment: Can't tell the fault from here. But Is there any reason why u set the appdelegate window instead of presenting a view modally?

Comment: @ZacKwan I've found it to be kinda more robust way to present login screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the storyboard and two finger click on all the ViewControllers in the navigation bar on the left side of the storyboard editors. A dark opaque pop up should appear with all your outlets and actions for that viewcontroller. If any of them have a yellow exclamation mark, click the x button to delete them (and obviously reconnect them if need be). Do this for all your view controllers. I hope this helps and let me know if you have any further issues. This problem plagued me a while back so I get how frustrating it is ;)